# I'm having problems with OpenGL textures in C++

Tags: c++, textures, glut, bmp

I'm having two big problems with my texture that I'm adding. The texture that I'm trying to use a bricks.bmp file.

The first problem is that whenever I use it, it seems to have a blueish tint to it. Here is the code I've used for it:

```
void Shape::buildBox(float x, float y, float z, float w, float d, float h)
{
    // Front face of box
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Resources::bricks->textureID);
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);

    glTexCoord3f(x - w, y, z + d);
    glVertex3f(x - w, y, z + d);

    glTexCoord3f(x - w, y + h, z + d);
    glVertex3f(x - w, y + h, z + d);

    glTexCoord3f(x + w, y, z + d);
    glVertex3f(x + w, y, z + d);

    glTexCoord3f(x + w, y + h, z + d);
    glVertex3f(x + w, y + h, z + d);

    glTexCoord3f(x + w, y, z - d);
    glVertex3f(x + w, y, z - d);

    glTexCoord3f(x + w, y + h, z - d);
    glVertex3f(x + w, y + h, z - d);

    glEnd();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

And here is what it looks like:
[image]

The other problem I'm having which I think relates to the code posted before as well is that when I try to lay out the bmp on a different axis, it gets all stretched out and distorted like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what I need to change? Is it something that is wrong with the BMP itself? I got the texture for the floor to work perfectly fine and I've tried using a variety of other BMPs for the "wall" that I'm making but the same thing seems to keep happening for all of them.

Comment: http://www.cs.iusb.edu/~danav/teach/c481/bricks.bmp <- here is the link to the BMP, since I couldn't post it in the question

Comment: The bricks looking blue could be a problem with the texture format. I suspect that the data is RGB, and the texture format `GL_BGR`, or vice versa.

Comment: The second problem is with the texture coordinates. For regular texture mapping, you typically only use two texture coordinates. The texture coordinates specify which part of your image gets mapped to which part of your geometry. It looks like you simply replicated the vertex positions as texture coordinates. That's not going to give you the desired result.